Use Scipy to try matrix optimization problem where the eigenvalues have absolute value 1
Consider the following optimization problem: For a given n, the optimized variable A0, B0, A1, B1 are dimension-2^n real symmetric matrices. All of their eigenvalues have absolute value 1. rho is a given dim-2^(2n) matrix. The objective function is max Tr[(A0⊗B0 +A0⊗B1+A1⊗B0 -A1⊗B1)*rho]. Here ⊗ is the Kronecker Product. The background is from the Tsirelson's bound in quantum information.
When n = 1, I tried to use Scipy optimize from Python to solve it, the code is:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

np.set_printoptions(precision = 8, suppress=True)
paulimatrices = np.zeros((4, 2, 2))

paulimatrices[0] = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]) 
paulimatrices[1] = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])  
paulimatrices[2] = np.array([[0, -1], [1, 0]]) #real
paulimatrices[3] = np.array([[1, 0], [0, -1]])

noise = 1.0


def objective_function(x, epr):
    A0 = x[:4].reshape((2, 2))  
    B0 = x[4:8].reshape((2, 2))
    A1 = x[8:12].reshape((2, 2))
    B1 = x[12:16].reshape((2, 2))
    A0 = A0 + A0.T
    B0 = B0 + B0.T
    A1 = A1 + A1.T
    B1 = B1 + B1.T
    D00 = np.kron(A0,B0)
    D01 = np.kron(A0,B1)
    D10 = np.kron(A1,B0)
    D11 = np.kron(A1,B1)
    return -np.trace((D00+D01+D10-D11) @ epr)
    
rho = 0.25*(np.kron(paulimatrices[0],paulimatrices[0])+noise*np.kron(paulimatrices[1],paulimatrices[1])+noise*np.kron(paulimatrices[2],paulimatrices[2])+noise*np.kron(paulimatrices[3],paulimatrices[3]))
A0_initial = np.eye(2)
B0_initial = np.eye(2)
A1_initial = np.eye(2)
B1_initial = np.eye(2)
initial_guess = np.hstack([A0_initial.flatten(), B0_initial.flatten(),A1_initial.flatten(),B1_initial.flatten()])

def constraint_func1(x):
    A0 = x[:4].reshape((2, 2))
    A0 = A0 + A0.T
    return np.trace(np.dot(A0,A0))-2
    # return np.trace(np.linalg.matrix_power(A0, 2))- 2
def constraint_func2(x):
    A0 = x[:4].reshape((2, 2))
    A0 = A0 + A0.T
    return np.trace(np.dot(np.dot(A0,A0),np.dot(A0,A0))) -2
    # return np.trace(np.linalg.matrix_power(A0, 4))- 2
def constraint_func3(x):
    B0 = x[4:8].reshape((2, 2))
    B0 = B0 + B0.T
    return np.trace(np.dot(B0,B0))-2
    # return np.trace(np.linalg.matrix_power(B0, 2))- 2
def constraint_func4(x):
    B0 = x[4:8].reshape((2, 2))
    B0 = B0 + B0.T
    return np.trace(np.dot(np.dot(B0,B0),np.dot(B0,B0))) -2
    # return np.trace(np.linalg.matrix_power(B0, 4))- 2
def constraint_func5(x):
    A1 = x[8:12].reshape((2, 2))
    A1 = A1 + A1.T
    return np.trace(np.dot(A1,A1))-2
    # return  np.trace(np.linalg.matrix_power(A1, 2))- 2
def constraint_func6(x):
    A1 = x[8:12].reshape((2, 2))
    A1 = A1 + A1.T
    return np.trace(np.dot(np.dot(A1,A1),np.dot(A1,A1))) -2
    # return  np.trace(np.linalg.matrix_power(A1, 4))- 2
def constraint_func7(x):
    B1 = x[12:16].reshape((2, 2))
    B1 = B1 + B1.T
    return np.trace(np.dot(B1,B1))-2
    # return  np.trace(np.linalg.matrix_power(B1, 2))- 2
def constraint_func8(x):
    B1 = x[12:16].reshape((2, 2))
    B1 = B1 + B1.T
    return np.trace(np.dot(np.dot(B1, B1),np.dot(B1,B1))) -2
    # return  np.trace(np.linalg.matrix_power(B1, 4))- 2
constraint1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_func1}
constraint2 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_func2}
constraint3 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_func3}
constraint4 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_func4}
constraint5 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_func5}
constraint6 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_func6}
constraint7 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_func7}
constraint8 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_func8}


result = minimize(objective_function, initial_guess, args=(rho,), constraints=[constraint1,constraint2,constraint3,constraint4,constraint5,constraint6,constraint7,constraint8])

A0_optimal = result.x[:4].reshape((2, 2))
B0_optimal = result.x[4:8].reshape((2, 2))
A1_optimal = result.x[8:12].reshape((2, 2))
B1_optimal = result.x[12:16].reshape((2, 2))
A0_optimal = A0_optimal + A0_optimal.T
B0_optimal = B0_optimal + B0_optimal.T
A1_optimal = A1_optimal + A1_optimal.T
B1_optimal = B1_optimal + B1_optimal.T
print("A0:")
print(A0_optimal)
print("B0:")
print(B0_optimal)
print("A1:")
print(A1_optimal)
print("B1:")
print(B1_optimal)
print(-result.fun)

print(np.trace(np.linalg.matrix_power(A0_optimal, 4))- 2)


Here to make the constraints differentiable, I change the constraint that the absolute value of the eigenvalues of A0 is 1 to Tr(A0^2)=2^n and Tr(A0^4)=2^n (the same for A1,B0,B1). From Cauchy-Schwarz inequality they are equivalent.
However, the result it gives doesn't satisfy the constraints. Tr(A_0^4) is about 3.97.
My questions:

Why is the Scipy program unable to give a feasible solution especially the initial point is feasible? Are the degree-4 constraints hard to calculate (but they are smooth functions)?

Are there any better ways to use the constraint that all eigenvalues have absolute value 1?



You can simply write down the eigenvalues of a 2x2 matrix. For the matrix [a,b],[c,d] they would simply be - possibly complex - values ((a+d)+-sqrt((a+d)^2+4bc))/2. Is there any good reason why you don’t simply use the absolute values of these in your constraints?

@lastchance You are right, but I also want to try the case for higher-dimension matrix, then it is hard to get the eigenvalues. But the problem now is that if I use trace to denote the constraint, it even doesn't work for dimension-2 case.I will supplement these in the question.

You say in your question that you want them to be symmetric. Your Pauli matrix[2] isn’t.

@lastchance the Pauli matrices are only used to calculate the matrix rho, if you print rho , you will find that rho is symmetric.

FYI (you might have already noticed this): when I run your code, result.success is False and result.message is 'Iteration limit reached'.  It is a good idea to always print these two attributes along with result.x.

I can't reproduce your problem. When I run your code the last thing it outputs is about 5e-12, which effectively means A0^4 has a trace of 2, as required. When I check, tr(M^2)=2 and tr(M^4)=2 for all the optimal matrices.

@lastchance I think that is very strange. What is -result.fun? Ideally it should be about 2.828 (My running result is 57.1349). And what are the result.success and result.message if you print them?

Apart from extra print messages at the end I ran your code "as is". -result.fun is 2.0000028110557504; result.success is True; result.message is Optimization terminated successfully

@lastchance Thanks, but Warren's comment showed that his result is different from yours. Does the result differ on different device? It is so strange.

Well, you can try https://trinket.io/python3/d51211c08a - it gives the same result as I got on my home desktop PC (run from the command line).
